# Creation of a resource library for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, tag-wiki

This question is based on [the question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/creation-of-a-new-tag-for-books-resource-recommendation-and-having-a-resource-li) asked at physics meta.SE.

Can we have a library feature/tab added somewhere at Stack Exchange sites under "Science" and "Technology" which comes to the immediate notice of most users, if not all (i.e., as soon as they open a/the Stack Exchange site(s) under "Science" and/or "Technology" without login in/signing up, and which should not come off as an ad or notification, but can be viewed all the time)?

Under the library feature/tab, a book recommendation FAQ can be added (based on numerous discussions on those sites). For example, [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations). Also, other repositories of a subject, such as a/an list/FAQ of legally available lecture notes on the WWW domain (for the said subject) which can be deemed off as standard/good, as well as a/an list/FAQ of video lectures on the said subject from numerous universities all over the world (and their video archives). The lists/FAQs can be maintained by moderators as well as reviewers or/and those who have one thousand reputation (or above), and it may be able to stop the "abuse" of the tag "resource-recommendation" as well as build a library (of sorts) for stack exchange sites under "Science" and "Technology" which would, in turn, benefit many people.

Comment: Adding this as a section to a tag wiki won't do?

Comment: @random: I am new to this site and wasn't aware of that tag. My bad. :)

Comment: Not asking you to add that as a tag, but why a new section of the site should be created when tag wiki will do what you outline?

Comment: @random: Because I often see many users asking for resources which have already been made available in the past. Those threads are marked off as duplicate and are closed. Well, that takes care of things, however, IMO, if a new section is created within the site, people won't feel the need to create the posts in the first place. This applies for users who haven't signed up for stack exchange sites, yet. They can simply google, and their search result can show up stack exchange sites with resources at their disposal, as per their need.

Answer (score 2):

Note: The [Book Recommendations proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87408/book-recommendations) at Area 51 did not get into Beta and has since been deleted.

---

I too see book (and other) recommendation questions as being problematic for the Stack Exchange sites that I frequent, but I cannot support your proposed solution.

Instead, I think those users who want book recommendations to be asked for and answered on the Stack Exchange should sign up for the [Book Recommendations proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87408/book-recommendations) at Area 51:

> Proposed Q&A site for people seeking recommendations for books to read
> given a stated interest in previously read books, authors, topics,
> themes, moods, settings, characters, and/or other specific criteria.

I suspect that there are a lot of users who would be happy to ask for, and find, book recommendations on the Stack Exchange network, but far fewer users who are willing to provide and maintain that content.

It is for this reason that I think recommendations questions and recommendations sites are a poor fit for the Stack Exchange network. However, I am interested to see if recommendations sites can be sustained.  I note that [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) currently has the [lowest percentage of questions answered](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered) of all sites.